# Using VLC media Player in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a video in .avi format which needs to be rendered in a UI developed using GWT.The video does not play in Windows Media Player but opens up smoothly in VLC media player.Is there some way to use VLC media player to render the video in the GUI without changing video format(or any other processing on the video).
Thanks,

Comment: I don't know a lot about the argument, maybe you can use/install some codecs?I don't know how it works but maybe you need to write something using the codec necessary for that video... hope it will be helpful in some way

Answer (score 0):

In pure GWT it's not possible. Imagine that GWT is environment of HTML and JavaScript language so you are limited by them and your app is encapsulated what browser serve to you. However you could put Java applet that could force to run VLC.
Another way of playing movie in the browser is to use flv player or use HTML5 (like youtube), but in this solution you must convert your video file.